# ReactNative JS text not Updating

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

After Successfully setup the React Native Environment,after running i got an screen by default text

"Welcome to React Native,To get started ,edit App.js,Double Tap R on your keyboard to reload,shake or press menu button for dev menu"

But my problem is that after changing the file in Text  App.js ,i can not able to see the change in my app,alwys showing the by default text.....

and also after shaking the app when i click the Reload button give an error Could not connect to development server..

can you suggest me how to resolve the above issue,,,,,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your server and app are connected to the same network

Comment: Make sure your server is running

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't set up your debug environment completely. This is link. ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html ) Maybe you could try it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set up your debug environment properly.

1. run `react-native start` in a terminal (the current dir has to be the project)
2. run `react-native run-android` in another terminal: your device has to be plugged using usb cable, and developer mode has to be actived.
3. The app will be installed in your device, shake your device and tap enable live reloading.
4. You can now modify text and your app will be updated just by ctrl+s

Enjoy !!!